# Upgrading ExtJS in old ASP.NET application from 2.3 to 6

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

Looking for some assistance. TLDR version: we have an  ASP.NET web app that leverages ExtJS 2.3 and we are looking to upgrade to the current ExtJS version. Trying to get my head around what we’re in for.

Now for the details. I will preface by saying that I am not an expert in ExtJS nor .NET development. In fact, I’m a novice pretty much across the board when it comes to web development, so please excuse any poor explanations or misuse of terms on my part. My team is developing a web app on a “custom” framework that was developed a number of years ago at our company. It’s based on some re-runnable code generation tools that take xml templates and spit out the necessary code files. Our project is an ASP.NET MVP application that uses .aspx pages and NHibernate for ORM. Our UI is created from ExtJS—the controls are defined in each page’s .js file and then “assembled” in the .aspx page. The codebehind contains web methods that leverage the presenter of the C# code. I’ve included a snippet to demonstrate what I’m talking about below.

.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Entity.aspx.cs" Inherits="View.Example.EntityView" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Content.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ext-2.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Factory/Example/Entity.js")%>"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var localConfig = new panelConfig();

localConfig.applyExtendedConfig('default_page');

localConfig.addItem(new Ext.grid.GridPanel(pageConfigs.default_page_ManageEntity));
localConfig.addItem(
    new Ext.form.Hidden({
    id: 'ManageEntityGrid_Rows'
    }));
var default_page = localConfig.createExt();
default_page.on('render', default_page_OnShow, default_page, { single: true });

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

.js file:

```
var get_manageEntity_columns = function() {
var columns = [
    { header: "Name"
    ,id: 'ManageEntity-col-Name'
    , dataIndex: 'Name'
    , sortable: true
    },

    { id: 'ManageEntity-col-ActiveFlag'
    , header: 'Active Flag'
    , dataIndex: 'ActiveFlag'
    , hidden: true
    ,tags: []
    , sortable: true
    },

    { id: 'ManageEntity-col-CreatedTimestamp'
    , header: 'Created Timestamp'
    , dataIndex: 'CreatedTimestamp'
    , hidden: true
    ,tags: []
    , renderer : formattedDateTime
    , sortable: true
    },

    { id: 'ManageEntity-col-Id'
    , header: 'Entity ID'
    , dataIndex: 'Id'
    , hidden: true
    ,tags: []
    , sortable: true
    }
];
return columns;
}

var get_grid_reader_manageEntity = function(custom_fields) {
    var fields = [
    { name: 'ActiveFlag', mapping: 'ActiveFlag' },
    { name: 'CreatedTimestamp', mapping: 'CreatedTimestamp' },
    { name: 'Id', mapping: 'Id' },
    { name: 'Name', mapping: 'Name' }
    ];
    if (custom_fields) {
        fields = fields.concat(custom_fields);
    }
    return new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'Results',
    totalProperty: 'Total',
    id: 'Id'
    }, fields);
}

var get_grid_datastore_manageEntity = function() {
    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.data.PageMethodProxy({
    pageMethod: 'GetManageEntity'
    }),
        reader: get_grid_reader_manageEntity()
    , remoteSort: true
    });

    store.loadOrReload = function() {
        if (store.rapidLoaded)
            store.reload();
        else
        {
            store.rapidLoaded = true;
            store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: gPageSize }
            });
        }
    }
    get_grid_datastore_manageEntity = function() { return store; };
    return store;
}

var pageConfigs = {
default_page_ManageEntity: {
    store: get_grid_datastore_manageEntity(),
    columns: get_manageEntity_columns(),
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    sm: get_manageEntity_sm(),
    layout:'fit',
    frame: true,
    id: 'ManageEntity',
    plugins: [
        grid_filters_manageEntity
        ],
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    loadMask: true,
    stripeRows: true,
    bbar: get_grid_paging_toolbar_manageEntity(),
    listeners: {
            rowcontextmenu: show_grid_menu_manageEntity
            ,bodyscroll: function() {
                var menu = get_grid_menu_manageEntity();
                if (menu.isVisible()) menu.hide();
            }
            ,headerClick: function() {
                this.getStore().on('beforeload', this.saveState, this, { single: true });
            }
            ,render: function(){
                var grid = this;
                Ext.onReady(function() {
                    add_applied_filters(grid);
                var grid_state = Ext.state.Manager.get('ManageEntity') || {};
                if (!grid_state.default_filter_applied) {
                    var filters = grid_filters_manageEntity;
                    var activeflag_filter = filters.getFilter("ActiveFlag");
                    activeflag_filter.setValue(["", new Array("1")]);
                    activeflag_filter.setActive(true);
                    grid.on('beforestatesave', function(grid, state) { state.default_filter_applied = true; });
                }
                    grid.getStore().load({ params: { start: 0, limit: gPageSize }
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}}
```

.aspx.cs file:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static ExtJSGridData GetManageEntity(PageProxyArgs args)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    try
    {
        var data = new ExtJSGridData();
        var criteria = GetManageEntityQuery(args);
        criteria.SetFirstResult(args.Start).SetMaxResults(args.Limit);
        data.Results = GetDataManageEntity(args.RecordId, criteria);
        criteria.SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(RowSelection.NoValue);
        criteria.ClearOrders();
        data.Total = criteria.SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("Id")).UniqueResult<int>();
        data.UserUiStateSaved = UserUiStateHelper.SaveUserUiStateInTransaction(args.UserUiState);
        watch.Stop();
        PageLogHelper.CurrentLog.ServerTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger((MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)).Error(ex);
        ErrorHandler.LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
}

private static IList GetDataManageEntity(int id, ICriteria criteria)
{
    var list = criteria.List<Model.BusinessObjects.Entity>();
    var jsonList = Model.BusinessObjects.Entity.ToJSON(list);
    return jsonList;
}

private static ICriteria GetManageEntityQuery(PageProxyArgs args)
{
    ICriteria criteria = StaticPresenter.GetEntity();

    var helper = new GridFilterHelper(criteria, args, _dManageEntityLookupSortInfo);
    helper.ApplyFilterMap(EntityJSON.GetGridFilterMap(criteria, args.Filters));

    MapManageEntityFilters(args.Filters, criteria);
    helper.ApplyFilters();

    if (args.SortInfo == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.SortInfo.FieldName))
        return criteria;

    IList<IProjection> sortMap = StaticPresenter.GetSortMap_ManageEntity(args.SortInfo.FieldName, args.RecordId, args.ExtraParams, criteria);
    if (sortMap == null)
        sortMap = EntityJSON.GetSortMap(args.SortInfo.FieldName, criteria);

    helper.ApplySort(sortMap);

    return criteria;
}
```

So, here is where the question comes in. As mentioned, the version of ExtJS we’re using is 2.3, and we’re looking to upgrade to the current version. I’ve done some initial homework of googling and looking through the sencha documentation, but there are some things which I’m unclear on and would like to get addressed before I start getting hands on with this effort. I’ve tried to outline my specific questions below.

First and foremost: Is the way our application is built even possible with ExtJS 6? By this, I mean leveraging the ExtJS API to define controls in the .js file and then create a UI on top of a .NET C# backbone. Based on the change notes and questions from other users, it’s pretty apparent that there have been massive (understatement) changes between 2.3 and 6. I guess what I’m getting at is that based on what I’ve read it seems you can now build your entire app, including the model and view (and controller?) in ExtJS. Is this a requirement, or can we still lay ExtJS controls on top of our .NET C# model and view?

As a follow up, I’ve been seeing references about Sencha CMD to create and build the app etc. Is cmd going to be required no matter what? Or can we simply reference the ext js library like we’re currently doing?

Assuming the answer to question 1 is yes it’s possible, the next obvious question becomes: how much work is this going to be? Let’s get the “a lot” answer out of the way—I know. What I do know is that we will have to update all of our templates to use the new API syntax (new Ext… to Ext.create() etc). I’m okay with this. What I’m trying to figure out is what I don’t know. Assuming I update all of the syntax, would our application work? Or are there other things I need to change/fix in order to get it working?

Related to question 2: based on my reading it looks like the way data stores for controls has changed and they now use the model defined in ExtJS. Is this a requirement? As described earlier, we’re currently using web methods in the aspx.cs file. Am I going to need to duplicate our C# model in ExtJS?

Lastly, I see this asked a lot but I can’t seem to find a definitive answer. Classic vs modern? The answer I typically see is that modern is aimed more towards touch screens and modern browsers, while classic is more geared toward desktop users. I’ve also read in places that modern has fewer controls available. Our web app is running in a local environment and will not be going to mobile in the future, which leads me to think classic might be the right choice? I guess I’m just wondering technically what the difference is.

I’m sure there are things I don’t even know I’m missing. Any and all feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will have to do a lot handwriting. Just three weeks ago I had to leverage a 3.4 ASP to 6.2.1

You can either set the variables to a global variable and on start add these to the mainView ViewModel or load them right away onBeforeLaunch.

Then code your app and build it using Sencha CMD. At the end add all together in your ASP stuff.

About how much work ... depends a lot on how structured your code is, how easy it will be to rewrite the code.

Let's pretend it is written in the same style all over the application, then it will be relatively easy.